# Searching for analytical or topological proof(s) of the Cayley-Hamilton theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, analysis

Is there any analytical or topological proof(s) of the Cayley-Hamilton theorem ? I want to know such proofs ( if possible ) , I would even appreciate proper references with accessible links .

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I think I remember seeing a proof in which the CHT was shown to hold for a dense set of matrices, and then extended by continuity. I think the dense set in question was the set of complex-diagonalizable matrices.

Comment: The theorem is purely algebraic. Any proof is bound to use some algebra. Some proofs involve some topology (together with the fact that the determinat is a contiuous function of the matrix coefficients); are you hinting at such a proof. WP gives one, at least it did the last time I looked.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen  : No , I know that continuity of determinant function  proof ....

Comment: @SouvikDey I'm unclear on what exactly your requirements for the proof are. Apparently you are banning the already very interesting one that uses the determinant.

Answer (score 1):

The CHT is obvious for diagonal matrices if you recall that:

1. Raising a diagonal matrix to a power simply raises its diagonal entries to that power.
2. Those diagonal entries are the eigenvalues of the matrix, and
3. The eigenvalues satisfy the characteristic polynomial.

We can easily extend the theorem to diagonalizable matrices instead of just already-diagonal ones. Now we use the fact that diagonalizable matrices are dense in the set of matrices (under a topology that makes $\det$ continuous). I can't remember how, but this can be used to extend the CHT by continuity to all matrices.